# Could not execute query on Login - Sign Up and Error uploading file with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a File Hosting Website and all is good but on Sign-up - Login - i get this error “Could not execute query”  and On Upload i get this error “Error uploading file”On. What could be the issue?

Here it my db.sql imported into phpMyAdmin

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: May 02, 2019 at 07:21 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+02:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `filehost`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_info` (
  `admin_index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `admin_pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `admin_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `admin_index` (`admin_index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin_info`
--

INSERT INTO `admin_info` (`admin_index`, `admin_id`, `admin_pass`, `admin_email`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'admin', 'codedmediaentertainment@gmail.com');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `files_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files_info` (
  `file_index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_delete_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_size` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_upload_date` date NOT NULL,
  `file_upload_time` time NOT NULL,
  `file_upload_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_upload_ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file_downloads_count` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `file_index` (`file_index`),
  UNIQUE KEY `file_code` (`file_code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `file_delete_id` (`file_delete_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=114 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_info` (
  `u_index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_reg_date` date NOT NULL,
  `u_reg_time` time NOT NULL,
  `u_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`),
  KEY `u_index` (`u_index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_info`
--

INSERT INTO `users_info` (`u_index`, `u_id`, `u_pass`, `u_email`, `u_ip`, `u_reg_date`, `u_reg_time`, `u_status`) VALUES
(38, 'guest', '%%%$$$ADAD>>>::""""::', 'RESERVED USER', 'RESERVED USER', '2011-10-24', '10:33:36', 'RESERVED USER'),
(39, 'user', 'user', 'ab@c.com', '::1', '2019-05-02', '22:50:25', 'active');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

html.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
        if((isset($_GET['download'])|| isset($_GET['delete'])))
            unset($_SESSION['uploaded_file']);
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>File Host</title>
        <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/red/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme_stylesheet" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>       

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function(){

                $('.ui-state-default').hover( 
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    },
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    }
                )

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="header"><h1>&nbsp;</h1></div>

            <div id="content" class="ui-corner-all">
                <h1>Share your files with the world</h1>

                <div id="date"></div>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['u_id'])!='')
                        {
                            echo '
                               <li><a href="account">Dashboard</a></li>
                               <li><a href="include/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            ';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="signup_form.php">Sign up</a></li>
                                ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <!--li><a href="#">Multi-Levels</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li--> 
                    <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="tabs" style="background-position: 50% 40px;">


                    <div id="main">
                        <div class="center" id="main">
                            <?php 

                                if(isset($_GET['delete'])!='')
                                {
                                    include('include/conn.php');
                                    $sql_delete_chk='
                                    SELECT *
                                        FROM `files_info`
                                        WHERE `file_delete_id` = "'.$_GET['delete'].'" AND `file_status` = "active";
                                    ';
                                    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql_delete_chk))==1)
                                    {
                                        $result_delete_file=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_delete_chk));
                                        echo '<h3>Confirm delete file</h3>
                                        <i>File Name:</i> '.$result_delete_file['file_name'].'

                                        <br/> <br/><i>File Size:</i> '.round(($result_delete_file['file_size']/1024),2).' KB
                                        <br/>
                                    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Confirm Delete File"  onclick="window.location=\'include/signup.php?deletefile='.$_GET['delete'].'\'" />
                                        ';                                  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<error>Cannot find file to delete</error>';
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(isset($_GET['download'])!='')
                                {
                                    include('include/conn.php');

                                    $sql_download_chk='
                                    select * from files_info where file_code="'.$_GET["download"].'" AND file_status="active";
                                    ';

                                    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql_download_chk))==1  && file_exists('uploads/'.$_GET["download"]))
                                    {
                                        $result_download_file=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_download_chk));
                                        $_SESSION['download_link_temp']=$_GET['download'];
                                        echo '<h3>Download file</h3>
                                        <i>File Name:</i> '.$result_download_file['file_name'].'

                                        <br/> <br/><i>File Size:</i> '.round(($result_download_file['file_size']/1024),2).' KB
                                        <br/>
                                    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Download File"  onclick="window.location=\'download.php\'" />
                                        ';                                  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<error>No File Found</error>';
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(isset($_GET['delete_file']))
                                {
                                    if($_GET['delete_file']=='successful')
                                        echo '<error>File deleted</error>';
                                    else if($_GET['delete_file']=='fail')
                                        echo '<error>Error deleting file</error>';
                                    else
                                        echo '<error>Invalid attempt</error>';
                                }

                                else if(isset($_SESSION['uploaded_file']['name'])!='')
                                {
                                    echo '
                                        <h3>Uploaded File Details</h3>                     

                                        <i>File Name:</i> '.$_SESSION['uploaded_file']['name'].'

                                        <br/> <br/><i>File Size:</i> '.round(($_SESSION['uploaded_file']['size']/1024),2).' KB';

                                    echo '
                                        <br/>
                                        <br/>
                                        <h3>Links for uploaded file</h3>                     


                                        <i>Download URL: </i>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?download='.$_SESSION['uploaded_file']['links']['download'].'<br/><br/><i>Delete URL: </i>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?delete='.$_SESSION['uploaded_file']['links']['delete'] ;    

                                        $_SESSION['temp_download_url']=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?download='.$_SESSION['uploaded_file']['links']['download'];
                                        $_SESSION['temp_delete_url']=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?download='.$_SESSION['uploaded_file']['links']['delete'];

                                    echo '
                                    <div style="display:block; height:50px;"></div>
                                    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Upload Another File"  onclick="window.location=\'include/signup.php?upload=new\'" />
                                        ';              

                                    echo '
                                    <div style="display:block; height:50px;"></div>
                                    <h3>Email me links</h3>
                                    <ul class="form floatleft">

                                <li><label class="desc"> Email ID: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> 
                                    <input size="43" id="email" name="email" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform"  onkeyup="send_data(\'email_status\');" onblur=" send_data(\'email_details_status\');" />

                                <span class="status" id="email_status"></span>
                                        <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" style="display:inline;" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Send Email" onclick="send_data(\'email_details_status\');"  />
                                        </li>                                       

                                    </ul>
                                      <br/>
                                       <span class="form_status" id="email_details_status"></span>';                
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    echo '
                                        <h3>Browse and upload file</h3>                     

                                       <form name="upload" action="include/signup.php" id="upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
                                            <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" />
                                       </form>                  
                                    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Upload File" style=" float:center; " onclick="document.upload.submit();" />
                                        ';
                                }
                            ?>

                            <?php
                                if(isset($_GET['error'])=='upload')
                                {
                                    echo "<error>Error uploading file</error>";
                                }
                            ?>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end main tab -->



                </div>
                <!-- end tabs -->

            </div>
            <!-- end content -->

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- end wrapper -->



    </body>

</html>
```

Login.php

```
<?php session_start() ;
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['u_id'])!='')
                        {
                            header("LOCATION:index.php");
                        }

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>File Host</title>
        <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/red/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme_stylesheet" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>       

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function(){

                $('.ui-state-default').hover( 
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    },
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    }
                )

            });
            function forgot_form()
            {
                if(document.getElementById('forgot_pass_form').style.display=='none')
                    document.getElementById('forgot_pass_form').style.display='block';
                else
                    document.getElementById('forgot_pass_form').style.display='none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="header"><h1>&nbsp;</h1></div>

            <div id="content" class="ui-corner-all">
                <h1>Share your files with the world</h1>

            <div id="date"></div>
              <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['u_id'])!='')
                        {
                            echo '
                               <li><a href="account">Dashboard</a></li>
                               <li><a href="include/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            ';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<li class="current"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="signup_form.php">Sign up</a></li>
                                ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <!--li><a href="#">Multi-Levels</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li--> 
                    <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs" style="background-position: 50% 40px;">

                <div id="login">
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                        <ul class="form floatleft">
                            <li><label class="desc">Username: </label> <input size="43" id="login_user" name="login_user" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" /></li>
                            <li><label class="desc">Password: </label> <input size="43" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" type="password" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" /></li>

                      <li>
                                <span id="contact_status"><a href="#" onclick="forgot_form()">Forgot password</a></span>
                                <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Login" onclick="send_data('login_status');"  />
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                       <br/>
                       <span class="form_status" id="login_status"></span>

                       <span id="forgot_pass_form" style="display:none">
                        <ul class="form floatleft">
                                <li><label class="desc">Username: </label> <input size="43" id="forgot_user" name="forgot_user" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" /></li>

                             <li>
                                    <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Send Password"  onclick="send_data('forgot_pass_status');"  />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                                <span class="form_status" id="forgot_pass_status"></span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end login tab -->



                </div>
                <!-- end tabs -->

            </div>
            <!-- end content -->

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- end wrapper -->


    </body>

</html>
```

signup_form.php

```
<?php session_start() ;
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['u_id'])!='')
                        {
                            header("LOCATION:index.php");
                        }

?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>File Host</title>
        <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/red/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme_stylesheet" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>       

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function(){

                $('.ui-state-default').hover( 
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    },
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
                    }
                )

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="header"><h1>&nbsp;</h1></div>

            <div id="content" class="ui-corner-all">
                <h1>Share your files with the world</h1>

            <div id="date"></div>
                 <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['u_id'])!='')
                        {
                            echo '
                               <li><a href="account">Dashboard</a></li>
                               <li><a href="include/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            ';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                                 <li class="current"><a href="signup_form.php">Sign up</a></li>
                                ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    <!--li><a href="#">Multi-Levels</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li--> 
                    <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="tabs" style="background-position: 50% 40px;">

                <div id="signup">
                        <h2>Sign Up</h2>                        
                        <div class="messages ui-corner-all" id="msg_contact"></div>
                            <ul class="form floatleft">
                                <li><label class="desc">Username: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> <input size="43" id="username" name="username" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" onkeyup="send_data('user_state');" onblur=" send_data('user_state');" />
                                <span class="status" id="user_state"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><label class="desc">Password: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> <input size="43" id="pass" name="pass" type="password" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" / onkeyup="send_data('pass_status');" onblur=" send_data('pass_status');" >
                                <span class="status" id="pass_status"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><label class="desc"> Confirm Password: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> <input size="43" name="confirm_pass" id="confirm_pass" type="password" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" onkeyup="send_data('confirm_pass_status');" onblur=" send_data('confirm_pass_status');" />
                                <span class="status" id="confirm_pass_status"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><label class="desc"> Email ID: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> <input size="43" id="email" name="email" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform"  onkeyup="send_data('email_status');" onblur=" send_data('email_status');" />
                                <span class="status" id="email_status"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><label class="desc"> Captcha: <font color="#FF0000">*</font></label> 
                                <div><img src="include/captcha.php" alt="captcha image" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:010px; float:left"/>
                                </div>
                                <input maxlength="6" id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" class="text required ui-corner-all cform" style="width:100px; margin-left:10px;"  onkeyup="send_data('captcha_status');" onblur="send_data('captcha_status');" />

                                <span class="status" id="captcha_status"></span>
                                </li>

                          <li>
                            <input class="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all floatright" type="submit" id="btn_contact" value="Sign up" onclick="send_data('form_status');" />
                                <span class="form_status" id="form_status"></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end signup tab -->



                </div>
                <!-- end tabs -->

            </div>
            <!-- end content -->

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- end wrapper -->


    </body>

</html>
```

account.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("LOCATION:login.php");
}

?>
```

see https://cmestudios.co.za/share

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't possibly know.

Comment: Got it @Obsidian . Can you help now

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions. They have been removed from PHP.

Comment: what must i use?

Comment: Newbie Alert @Dharman